# Choosing a color from an array of them just returns black?

Tags: arrays, random, colors, processing

Here's my situation.  I'm using Processing 2.0, and I'm trying to make a grid of squares turned at a 45-degree angle.  Each square will be filled with a color chosen randomly from a palette of five.  My problem is this; for some reason, when I use `COLORS[int(random(COLORS.length))]` to get a color from my palette, I only get black!  It's doubly weird because black is not one of the colors in my palette!  I have tested my `floodFill()` function, and I can confirm that it works, as testing with a single color *not* pulled from an array works all right.  Any tips?  My code is as follows:

```
final int DX = 16, DY = DX;
final color DEFAULT_BG = color(50, 50, 50);
final color[] COLORS = {
  color(#ff3333),
  color(#4fff55),
  color(#585eff),
  color(#ebff55),
  color(#FF55D5),
};

void setup() {
  size(800, 480);
  background(DEFAULT_BG);
  noSmooth();
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x += DX) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y += DY) {
      line(x, y, x + 16, y + 16);
      line(x + 16, y, x, y + 16);
    }
  }

  for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 4) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y += 4) {
      if (get(x, y) == DEFAULT_BG) {
        color f = COLORS[int(random(COLORS.length))];
        floodFill(x, y, DEFAULT_BG, color(f));
      }
    }
  }
}

void floodFill(final int x, final int y, final color from, final color to) {
  if (!(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height || from == to || get(x, y) != from)) {
    set(x, y, to);
    floodFill(x, y + 1, from, to);
    floodFill(x, y - 1, from, to);
    floodFill(x + 1, y, from, to);
    floodFill(x - 1, y, from, to);
  }
}
```

When I replace the `#rrggbb` notation with `0xrrggbb`, I get white instead.  When I replace it with `0xrrggbbaa`, I get black and white (not grayscale).

Now using the standard `color(r, g, b)` notation works fine.  However, I'd still like to know what breaks the hexadecimal versions, so I'll leave this question open.

Comment: The sample code isn't working due to missing closing parentheses in line 34, after column 86: ...from) **)** ...

Comment: Whoops.  Fixed.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

color() does not take hex values. It takes simple int values from 0 - 255. Try printing out the value of one of your color() calls with hex values in it and you'll get some crazy negative value.

Any negative value fed into the color() method will be interpreted as 0, which equals black. Try it in Processing if you'd like to see its affect.

Like you figured it out, use color(r,g,b) using values ranging from 0 - 255 for r, g, b respectively.